# Accessing restful services from wso2dss to wso2esb

Tags: rest, curl, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I'm using wso2dss 3.1.0 and wso2esb 4.7.0..I have created a restful dataservice in dss and it's working fine for all operations like get,post,update and delete.Now I wish to user this dataservice in esb..for this i have created a proxy with following configuration :

```
 <target>
         <endpoint>
            <address uri="http://192.168.1.23:9764/services/A_resttest/"
                     format="soap11"/>
         </endpoint>
         <outSequence>
            <send/>
         </outSequence>
      </target>
```

And tried to execute with curl command like this :

```
curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" http://youtility-desktop:8282/services/RestTest1
```

But it showing warning and error like :

```
WARN - SourceHandler Connection time out after request is read: http-incoming-1
ERROR - NativeWorkerPool Uncaught exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:156)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
WARN - SourceHandler Connection time out after request is read: http-incoming-2
```

I have referred https://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB460/Using+REST+with+a+Proxy+Service.
Is the procedure is correct or their is problem in curl command?Please let me know..I have tried this by creating api also but showing same error..Should i uncomment any code in axis2 file?

Answer (score 0):

Are you going to expose the DSS service via SOAP using ESB? If not, I'd like to suggest that you create ESB REST API instead of a proxy service to expose the DSS service.

Secondly, you have set `format="soap11"` for the dss service endpoint. But as I understand from your question, you need to use rest format instead of soap 1.1. So, change the format to `format="rest"` or `format="pox"` depending on your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for reply KasunBG ..I wish to expose restful dss service via **rest** using esb..So let me try the rest api

Comment: hi @KasunBG..Still i'm facing same error **NativeWorkerPool Uncaught exception java.lang.NullPointerException**..Whatever changes i have made it displaying same error at server side i.e. At the esb side..Is it related to any configuration setting or changes in axis2 file?